# How to create reminder for user in Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm creating Laravel website. I need that user (who is logged in) should be able to sets reminder only for him. For example he select that his ticket expiry date is 2019-06-11, and before 2 days he gets notification/reminder that ticket is going to expire soon. How to do that? 
Thank you.

Comment: You want us to code this whole functionality for you?

Comment: You can do with cronjob for send notification

Comment: No, not the whole code, just give an idea or something what should i use, what to search for?

Answer (score 3):

You should look towards [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) in Laravel. Then in your `app/Console/Kernel.php` file you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // This code will be scheduled for execution every day at 8:00 am.
    $schedule->call(function () {
        // Get all tickets that are about to expire in the next 2 days.
        $tickets = \App\Ticket::whereBetween('expires_at', [now(), now()->addDays(2)])->get();

        // Send notifications for those tickets owners.
        $tickets->each(function ($ticket) {
            $ticket->user->notify(new \App\Notifications\TicketExpirationReminder($ticket));
        });
    })->dailyAt('08:00');
}
```

Code I presented is something you can use as an example for how something you asked about is done. You should also check out how [notifications can be set up in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications).